# Expense report app

Tags: admin

I need to create expense report with some fields that must capture following types of expenses: airplane, hotel stay and the food.

The report user fills in report with trip name and we must allow him to add the expenses he did but only show the information specific to the type,, for example for airplane only american airlines or delta or alaksa air, but for food breakfast or lunch or dinner.

Comment: Salesforce isn't difficult, it's simply overwhelmingly expansive. What you need to do is to find out where you need to start. Once you start, everything gets easier.

Comment: Dependent picklists

Answer (score 0):

Like the AppStore and Playstore, you can directly download and install a ready to use application from the [Salesforce Appexchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxHome) which is a market place for Salesforce business apps.

> Refer the following free apps on Appexchange meant for expense management and should
>   match most of your requirements. You may need to customize some bit of
>   the app but that should not be too hard. You do not have to be limited
>   to the ones listed below and can search for other apps
>   as well!
>
> - [Expense Tracker](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016aUiEAI)
> - [Entertainment Expense Management](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YJGEA2)

If you really are inclined to building the app yourself and learning Salesforce then I would recommend you follow the advice above. You can leverage [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home) a free platform to learn and get acquainted with Salesforce.